# Spring batch JDBCPagingItemReader, ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and multiple pods in OpenShift

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, openshift, spring-batch

We have a Spring batch application with chunk processing which reads records from DB, processes them and calls a service/performs a few inserts/updates a few tables in the DB as part of writer.

`JDBCPagingItemReader` has been used as it is thread safe when saveState is false.
A sort key has been set so the threads dont cross each other. 
Also isolation level `ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED` has been used for the oracle datasource and `JobRepository` configuration of Spring batch.

Multiple threads using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is working great currently in a single instance.

We should eventually deploy this Spring Boot application in OpenShift where the application will run in multiple PODS i.e multiple instances of the application which all read from the same table.

Could someone who has the knowledge, let me know if there would be any problem using the above combination in multiple pods ( instances ) or if there would be concurrency issues which have to be dealt with .

Any best practices in this scenario are highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what about making each instance (multi-threaded job) handle a different portion of the table? That would solve the problem by design.

Comment: Each multi-thread job is already handling different set of rows using JDBCPagingItemReader using sortKeys. But this all happens within a pod of openshift or inside a VM. But my concern is across multiple pods or multiple VM's. I am afraid multiple instances dealing with different set of data doesnt apply in our scenario, but I am curious to know how it can configured.

Comment: My comment was about multiple pods, I added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can partition the table and assign each partition to a pod. Then, each partition is handled by a multi-threaded job. So there are two degrees of parallelism here: across pods (multiple JVMs) and with-in each pod (multiple threads).

> Could someone who has the knowledge, let me know if there would be any problem using the above combination in multiple pods ( instances ) or if there would be concurrency issues which have to be dealt with .

There would be no concurrency issues if the dataset is correctly partitioned with no overlap between partitions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our partition is based on Month-Year and sadly both pods have to retrieve data from the same partition. I do have a check where each record processed updates a field in the table. Currently when duplicate records are picked across pod's , the instance which fails to update the field doesnt progress further.